# Upgrading to vuetify to 2.0: stylus/sass obstacle

Tags: sass, vuetify.js, stylus

I would like to upgrade vuetify from 1.5 to 2.0 and get an access to the new features and components. But it seems there's a serious obstacle because it migrated from stylus to sass.

My project uses stylus. Actually vuetify was the only reason why I choose stylus over sass at the beginning. My code widely uses vuetify mixins and variables.

What should I do now?

1. One option is to pull mixins and variables from vuetify 1.5. Probably it's the easiest for now, but I don't like it since it removes the connection with new vuetify variables in future.
2. Move to sass as well. It's a lot of work. That's the next question. How you, guys from vuetify team, migrated vuetify to sass by yourselves? Have you used any conversion tool? I haven't found any.

Comment: you should ask this on their Github repo